# Can't upload messages to Atlas cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to implement a messaging app(Node.js) for my website. I found a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jD7FnbI76Hg) that solves my prob with Socket.io, so 99% of the work is complete. Now I'm trying to save this data, or the messages to my Atlas Cluster, but it doesn't work.

I identified my mistake but I don't know how to fix it. If I let the router.post("/") like this, it doesn't save anything in db. If I try to include the url, router.post("/username=a&room=JavaScript") it gives me this error:

```
C:\Users\marjo\chatcord\server.js:70
    io.to(user.room).emit("message", formatMessage(user.username, msg));
               ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'room' of undefined
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\marjo\chatcord\server.js:70:16)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at C:\Users\marjo\chatcord\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:528:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

Note: The code below only contains my contribution to the app, and it isn't the minimum reproducible example. The actual project has way too many files and I know you guys won't read them at all. If you want to go through the hassle and help me, here's the github repo of the project: https://github.com/bradtraversy/chatcord

Here's the code:

./routes/router.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const msg = require("../model/msg");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

router.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.body.msg) {
    var msgLog = {
      msg: req.body.msg,

      //   msg1: req.body.msg,document.forms["chat-form"]["msg"].value,
    };
    msg.create(msgLog, function (err, msg) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Msg sent to db");
      }
    });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

./model/msg.js

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

var MsgSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: String,
  },
  msg: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: String,
    default: new Date(),
  },
});

var Msg = mongoose.model("Msg", MsgSchema);
module.exports = Msg;
```

the part that I added to server.js

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const routes = require("./routes/router");
app.use("/", routes);

const URI =
  "mongodb+srv://Marjo:<myPassHere>@remote-doc-otc5a.mongodb.net/Rem_D?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
mongoose.connect(URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
var db = mongoose.connection;

//Test if server is connected to db
mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
  console.log("Mongoose is connected!!!!");
});

// handle mongo error
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", function () {
  // we're connected!
});
```

I'd appreciate if you could help me!

Comment: install `body-parser` package

Comment: I already did, I'm not a total newbie xD